# Overflow error mid calculation. Promote to long or straight to double?

Tags: c#

I had the following line of code in use:

```
points[x].TVAR = outerSum / (6 * n * n * outerΣMax);
```

`outerSum` and `TVAR` are `double`s, the rest are `int`s. My code in the parenthesis was calculated as an int and overflowing. Should I promote the values to a `long` or a `double` to overcome this error? Does it make a difference?

Promote to `long`:

```
points[x].TVAR = outerSum / (6L * n * n * outerΣMax);
```

Or promote to `double`:

```
points[x].TVAR = outerSum / (6.0 * n * n * outerΣMax);
```

**Edit:**

My main concern here is not loss of precision as it will be lost eventually anyway, but rather efficiency. Promoting from and `int` to a `long` in theory seems more efficient to me than promoting from and `int` to a `double`. Also is a `double` operation slower than a `long` operation? Maybe I'm over thinking/optimizing but that is what I am trying to ascertain.

Comment: does for all values of `n` the inner calculation overflows? or for only large values of n

Comment: @Rahul Only for the larger values of n.

Comment: If you are concerned about which is faster, ask your computer instead of us. The multiplication may be slower as a `double`, but the division might be *faster*. You can answer the question better than we can.

Comment: @Fr33dan Definitely you are over over over over thinking/optimizing. First of all, you're basing on a blind guess that "it seems faster to you" (not sure what's the "in theory" part is doing there, if it's "to you" :p) - this doesn't make sense. Secondly, the difference between such operations almost always will be negligible. You're wasting your time thinking about this. Just measure the execution time of both versions to see that wondering about this is pointless :)

Comment: @BartoszKP "in theory to me" means "by my understanding of the theory". Please don't make fun of the way I talk, if it is unclear ask for clarification. Less bits need to be moved/set to promote to a `long` and no effort is needed to check the size for the significand which seems faster. As for measuring it, that will only tell me how it operates on my CPU architecture. It may behave differently on an x86 vs x64. However, I do think I am overworking it through having read peoples comments and will likely just use a `double` and not think about it anymore.

Comment: @Fr33dan No making fun of you was intended, sorry. I just meant that theoretical implications are not subjective, so that phrase sounded strange to me :) Either you *know* what are these implications (in that case you should be able to present concrete arguments for them), either you're just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `outerSum` is `double` you end up with `double` anyway. This is because of the rules of overload resolution, mainly [Section 7.4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), in the context of [Section 7.2.4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691326%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Shortly:

> The overload resolution rules of Section 7.4.2 are applied to the set of candidate operators to select the best operator with respect to the argument list

---

> Given the set of applicable candidate function members, the best function member in that set is located.

where *better* is defined in [Section 7.4.2.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which implies which overload is the *best*.

So converting to `long` at first is pointless, and may be confusing for someone reading your code. Therefore, I think the second version is recommended.

Comment: Your answer is filled with good information but is not what I was seeking. See the edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to double would be ideal since that is eventually the type used.

In theory long can provide more accuracy but you would be losing it soon after anyway.

Comment: Only for overflowing purpose it's fine; otherwise since outerSum is of double type entire expression will result in double.

Comment: @Rahul: seems roundabout to me to use long if you are going to double soon.

Answer (score 0):

Per comment since only for large values of n the inner calculation overflows, you can do the conversion conditionally (kind of) using `checked` statement like below. Otherwise, since `outerSum` is of double type entire expression `outerSum / (6 * n * n * outerΣMax)` will evaluate in double type.

so, only for large values of `n` when it overflows and raise exception, in your `catch` statement you are converting to double which should go fine. See about [checked (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx)

```
    try
    {
        // The following line raises an exception because it is checked.
        points[x].TVAR = checked(outerSum / (6 * n * n * outerΣMax));
    }
    catch (System.OverflowException e)
    {
        // The following line displays information about the error.
        points[x].TVAR = outerSum / (6.0 * n * n * outerΣMax);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Also, if you can find out that for which specific large value of n (I mean starting value) overflow occurs then just use a if condition and handle your conversion there accordingly.

```
points[x].TVAR = (n >= 10000)? outerSum / (6.0 * n * n * outerΣMax) 
: outerSum / (6 * n * n * outerΣMax)
```

Comment: This operation is run in an O(N²) (not `n`) operation. Potentially catching an exception that many times seems very inefficient. When I say the "larger value" it could be as many as half of them. `n` does not increase linearly.

Comment: @Fr33dan, correct it will but that also avoids making it double type entirely. it's just an alternative which may/may not suit based on your requirement. in that case, you are better off by `6.0 * n * n * outerΣMax`

Comment: An interesting idea, but I'm not sure it is more efficient since you are adding an operation.

Comment: @Fr33dan, an extra operation is condition check which won't eat up much time. Use `stopwatch` class and check how long it takes with/without that extra condition check. I am sure you will not see much difference.

Comment: It's confusing that you say "using checked statement like below", and then show some sample code that does not have any "checked" statement - at least I can't see it.

Comment: @RenniePet, correct; I missed it while typing, am not good at typing. Thanks for pointing that.